# Showing Invalid Arguments Error Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm creating a registration form with the help of a Google spreadsheet Apps Script. The code is below; the identical code works completely fine with other Google accounts, but when I transfer it to the main account to publish it after altering the spreadsheet id and folder id, it fails and shows error  **Exception: Invalid argument: id**

***code.gs***

```
// 1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
// 2. Run > setup
//
// 3. Publish > Deploy as web app
// - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
// - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
// 4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
// 5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the
//parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new
//property service
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("SIPP Registrations");
// return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setFaviconUrl("");
}
function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, whatsapp, year, email, gender, college, domain, company, tel) {
try {
var dropbox = "Received Files";
//var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1H_52_xxh1rrzSjZyVrHl4pawMtLpeFqE');
/*
if (folders.hasNext()) {
folder = folders.next();
} else {
folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}
*/
/* Credit: www.labnol.org/awesome */
var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')), bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)), blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join(" ")).createFile(blob),
filelink=file.getUrl() ;
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
// next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1Rq0gWdVVWXkN3JI0P-Lv2i7b_Dmk4UMKDUgzr_V5v1k"));
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
// we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with
//header_row in GET/POST data
var headRow = 1;
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = [];
// loop through the header columns
for (i in headers){
if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a'Timestamp' column
row.push(new Date());
} else if (headers[i] == "name"){
row.push(name);
} else if (headers[i] == "whatsapp"){
row.push(whatsapp);
} else if (headers[i] == "year"){
row.push(year);
} else if (headers[i] == "email"){
row.push(email);
} else if (headers[i] == "gender"){
row.push(gender); 
} else if (headers[i] == "college"){
row.push(college);
} else if (headers[i] == "domain"){
row.push(domain);
} else if (headers[i] == "company"){
row.push(company);
} else if (headers[i] == "tel"){
row.push(tel);
} else if (headers[i] == "filelink"){
row.push(filelink);
}
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
// return json success results
//return ContentService
// .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
// .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
return "OK";
} catch (f) {
return f.toString();
} finally { //release lock
lock.releaseLock();
}
}
function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("1Rq0gWdVVWXkN3JI0P-Lv2i7b_Dmk4UMKDUgzr_V5v1k", doc.getId());
}
```

***forms.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingLab - www.codinglabweb.com -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!---<title> Responsive Registration Form | CodingLab </title>--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lol.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6);
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 700px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 25px 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        }

        .container .title {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            position: relative;
        }

        .container .title::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6);
        }

        .content form .user-details {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 20px 0 12px 0;
        }

        form .user-details .input-box {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
        }

        form .input-box span.details {
            display: block;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .user-details .input-box input {
            height: 45px;
            width: 100%;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom-width: 2px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .user-details .input-box select {
            height: 45px;
            width: 100%;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom-width: 2px;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .user-details .input-box input:focus,
        .user-details .input-box input:valid {
            border-color: #9b59b6;
        }

        form .gender-details .gender-title {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        form .category {
            display: flex;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 14px 0;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        form .category label {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        form .category label .dot {
            height: 18px;
            width: 18px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background: #d9d9d9;
            border: 5px solid transparent;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        #dot-1:checked~.category label .one,
        #dot-2:checked~.category label .two,
        #dot-3:checked~.category label .three {
            background: #9b59b6;
            border-color: #d9d9d9;
        }

        form input[type="radio"] {
            display: none;
        }

        form .button {
            height: 45px;
            margin: 35px 0
        }

        form .button input {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 500;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6);
        }

        form .button input:hover {
            /* transform: scale(0.99); */
            background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6);
        }

        @media(max-width: 584px) {
            .container {
                max-width: 100%;
            }

            form .user-details .input-box {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            form .category {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .content form .user-details {
                max-height: 300px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            .user-details::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 5px;
            }
        }

        @media(max-width: 459px) {
            .container .content .category {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var stateObject = {
            "Human Resource": {
                "Zoopero Marketing Limited": [],
            },
            "Digital Marketing": {
                "Zoopero Marketing Limited": [],
            },
            "Businees Dev Executive": {
                "Analytics Valley technologies": [],
                "Material Library India": [],
            },
            "Market Researcher": {
                "Acadspace technologies": [],
            },
            "Mern Stack": {
                "Jackfruit": [],
            },
            "Social Media Manager": {
                "Trinano Technologies": [],
            },
            "PHP & Laravel": {
                "Analytics Valley technologies": [],
            },
            "React JS Developer": {
                "Analytics Valley technologies": [],
            }
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            var domain = document.getElementById("domain"),
                company = document.getElementById("company"),
                districtSel = document.getElementById("districtSel");
            for (var country in stateObject) {
                domain.options[domain.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
            }
            domain.onchange = function () {
                company.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
                for (var state in stateObject[this.value]) {
                    company.options[company.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
                }
            }
            domain.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
            company.onchange = function () {
                districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
                if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done
                var district = stateObject[domain.value][this.value];
                for (var i = 0; i < district.length; i++) {
                    districtSel.options[districtSel.options.length] = new Option(district[i], district[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Registration</div>
        <div class="content">
            <form action="" class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="user-details">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Full Name</span>
                        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true"
                            placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Whatsapp Number</span>
                        <input type="number" name="whatsapp" id="whatsapp" class="validate" required=""
                            aria-required="true" placeholder="Enter Your Number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Email</span>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true"
                            placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Select Year</span>
                        <select id="year" name="year" required>
                            <option value="1st Year">1st Year</option>
                            <option value="2nd Year">2nd Year</option>
                            <option value="3rd Year">3rd Year</option>
                            <option value="4th Year">4th Year</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Prefered Domain</span>
                        <select id="domain" name="domain" required>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Domain</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Prefered Company</span>
                        <select id="company" name="company" required>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Company</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="district" id="districtSel" size="1" style="display: none;">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Please select State first</option>
                        </select><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Enter Your College Name</span>
                        <input id="college" type="text" name="college" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true"
                            placeholder="Enter your college" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <span class="details">Upload Resume</span>
                        <input type="file" id="files" placeholder="Upload your resume" required
                            accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="details">Gender</span>
                    <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Gender</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Prefer Not To Say">Prefer Not To Say</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <div id="progress">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">
                </div>
                <div id="success" style="display:none">
                    <h5 class="left-align teal-text">File Uploaded</h5>
                    <p>Your file has been successfully uploaded.</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materializ e.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var file, reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            if (e.target.error != null) {
                showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
                return;
            } else {
                google.script.run
                    .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
                    .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#name').val(), $('input#whatsapp').val(), $('select#year').val(), $('input#email').val(), $('select#gender').val(), $('input#college').val(), $('select#domain').val(), $('select#company').val(), $('input#tel').val());
            }
        };
        function showSuccess(e) {
            if (e === "OK") {
                $('#forminner').hide(); $('#success').show();
            } else {
                showError(e);
            }
        }
        function restartForm() {
            $('#form').trigger("reset"); $('#forminner').show(); $('#success').hide(); $('#progress').html("");
        }
        function submitForm() {
            var files = $('#files')[0].files;
            if (files.length === 0) {
                showError("Please select a file to upload");
                return;
            }
            file = files[0];
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
                showError("The file size should be < 5 MB. ");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Uploading file ...");
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        function showError(e) {
            $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
        }
        function showMessage(e) {
            $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').material_select();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

please help me to make it run.
Here Is The Main Account Error.
[image]

Here Is The Test Account Page Which Works Fine.
[image]

***My Code also works fine it stores the files in drive after showing error but not saving details in spreadsheet.***

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1Rq0gWdVVWXkN3JI0P-Lv2i7b_Dmk4UMKDUgzr_V5v1k"));
```

by

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Rq0gWdVVWXkN3JI0P-Lv2i7b_Dmk4UMKDUgzr_V5v1k");
```